# Choose from selected values from the form to populate one column in the DB table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I've managed to commit data from my vb.net form fields into a SQL table with a auto-incremented unique ID successfully.  The problem I have is that I have multiple form fields that have the same field name.  For example, I would a field within my database to accept data from TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3 OR TextBox4 on my form.  Is this possible?

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Using message As New MailMessage()
        Dim iReturn As Boolean

        Using con As New SqlConnection("Server=SGI-NOT-TTID01;Database=Commission;uid=****;pwd=******")
            Using com As New SqlCommand()
                With com
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO InputTable VALUES (@UniqueRequestNumber, @BusinessUnit, @ReasonCode, @Originator, @OnBehalfofName, @OnBehalfofEmail, @SalesTeam_CS, @SalesTeam_MISDBM, @DateEffectiveFrom, @DateEffectiveTo, @CustomerClientName, @CustomerAccNum, @MovingTo, @JustificationComments, @NewBusOrRenewal, @OthersImpacted, @ReasonCode2, @Target, @TargetPeriod, @ProposedScheme, @NewOTC, @ExistingRole, @Amount, @CustomerImapcted, @CurrentOTC, @PoundsInPocketEst, @NewRole ) "
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    .CommandText = "AddUniqueRequestNumberWithOutput"
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqueRequestNumber", ParameterDirection.Output)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessUnit", ComboBox1.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReasonCode", ComboBox4.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Originator", TextBox1.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnBehalfofName", TextBox2.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnBehalfofEmail", TextBox3.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesTeam_CS", ComboBox2.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesTeam_MISDBM", ComboBox3.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEffectiveFrom", DateTimePicker1.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEffectiveTo", DateTimePicker2.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerClientName", TextBox4.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAccNum", TextBox5.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovingTo", TextBox6.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@JustificationComments", TextBox7.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewBusOrRenewal", ComboBox6.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@OthersImpacted", TextBox13.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReasonCode2", ComboBox5.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Target", TextBox5.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetPeriod", ComboBox7.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProposedScheme", TextBox24.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewOTC", TextBox17.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExistingRole", TextBox19.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", TextBox8.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerImpacted", TextBox12.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentOTC", TextBox16.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PoundsInPocketEst", TextBox10.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRole", TextBox20.Text)

                End With
                Try
                    con.Open()
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    iReturn = True
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                    iReturn = False
                Finally
                    con.Close()
                End Try

                    'set to the from, to and subject fields
                    message.From = (New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text.ToString()))
                    message.[To].Add(New MailAddress("benjamin.boothe@experian.com"))
                    message.Subject = "Request Number"

                    If Not attachmentList Is Nothing Then
                    For Each attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment In attachmentList
                            message.Attachments.Add(attachment)
                        Next
                    End If



                    'display submitted box
               MessageBox.Show("Your request has been submitted!", "Congratulations!")
                    'close form
                    Me.Close()

                    Dim client As New SmtpClient()
                    client.Host = "mailhost"
                    client.Send(message)






            End Using
        End Using



    End Using

    Return
End Sub
```

So the logic behind this function is as follows:

1. Commits values to the table in SQL Server.
2. Sends a email (optionally with attachments).

Comment: So you want your database field store the values of more than one textbox?

Comment: Yes.  Not at the same time though. Just depending on which textbox has been populated on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a private function that search the textboxes and return the contents of the first one with text.

```
Private Function SearchBehalfText() As String
    Dim behalfOf = TextBox3.Text.Trim
    if behalfOf.Length = 0 then 'textbox3 is empty, check the next one '
        behalfOf = TextBox4.Text.Trim
        if behalfOf.Length = 0 then  'textbox4 is empty, check the next one '
             ...... mode test here if you have more textboxes, stop when all the textboxes are verified for empty
        End If
    End If
    return behalfOf
End Function
```

Now your code to create the parameter could be written as

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnBehalfofEmail", SearchBehalfText())
```

I find this scenario a bit weak. Restore the appropriate textbox is not feasible with this information

Comment: Thanks for that Steve. But this wouldn't work as my code to create the parameter is within the another private function that is a button click that submits the form.  If that makes sense to you?....

Comment: I don't understand how do you plan to retrieve the value from the textboxes then. When you set the parameter value you should choose what textbox content to use. If they are not available you need to pass that value here. Probably a bit more of the code around the line above and a clarification on the context will be of help

Comment: Ok Steve, I hope this is a bit clearer for you.  I've edited my question at the top. Just can't see how I'm going to add your sound, logical explanation to my complicated function. Thanks.

Comment: Just add the function that I have given in my answer to the same  class where your `Button3_Click` exists. Then change the line that creates the parameter `@onBehalfofEmail` as explained above. Instead of trying to OR together two or more textboxes text call the function `SearchBehalfText` that returns the string from the one of the textboxes you have decided to use for the field